# Unable to instantiate my custom element dynamically through its default constructor

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I have created a custom element that I want to use on my website, when I declare it in html document the constructor gets called and the element is instantiated and displayed withou any error. But when I want to instantiate it in code it seem to be missing a reference to its constructor using new CustomElement() .

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- 
    ...
-->

<script src="/custom_elements.js" defer ></script>   

<!-- 
    ...
-->


<style>



</style>



<script >


    function init(){

        var ele = new CustomElement();
        // !! does not work



    }



</script>

</head>


<body onLoad="init();" >

<custom-element></custom-element>
<!-- works -->

</body>
</html>
```

// within custom_elements.js the class is defined as

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        // code that gets displayed flawlessly when instantiated from html 


    }



}


customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement );
```

Error says: "CustomElement not defined"..

So it seems that there is some reference missing because when I paste the definition of my CustomElement inside the  tag where my code is then it works..
So how do I load the file that my script has reference to it as well, not only HTML code..
Thank you for any advice on how these things work

EDIT/REASON OF THE ERROR

So it seems there is logically nothing wrong with this implementation but my custom_elements.js file had an if/else clause within which the elements were defined..
It was

```
if(!customElementsSupported){

    // custom elements not supported action

}else{

    // definitions of custom elements

}
```

I assume that this must have put the custom elements inside a local scope thus preventing them to be accessible for my functions

Comment: get rid of "defer" in the `<script>` tag

Comment: That seem logical but.. it does not make any difference I am still getting "CustomElement is not defined".. it makes no sense.. I was also thinking that defer puts it behind the other code so it has no reference to it.. but it makes no difference..

Comment: I tried to give the other script a defer parameter as well but to no avail..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments you can get rid of `defer` in your `<script>` tag.

Or you just need to know when the class is available by using `customElements.whenDefined(name);`

If you make this change in your `init` function it will work:

```js
function init(){
  let ele;
  customElements.whenDefined('custom-element').then(
    function() {
      ele = new CustomElement();
    }
  );
}
```

This waits for the element to be defined, which will not happen until the class exists. So you are then safe to instantiate your element any way you want.

**UPDATE**

You can also create your object using `document.createElement` but you still have to wait until the element is defined.

```js
function init(){
  customElements.whenDefined('custom-element').then(
    function() {
      let ele = document.createElement('custom-element');
      // Do things with your element
    }
  );
}
```

**FURTHER UPDATE**

I created two file:

`custom_elements.js`

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    alert('constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    alert('connectedCallback');
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

And `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="custom_elements.js" defer></script>
  <script>
  function init() {
    customElements.whenDefined('custom-element').then(
      function () {
        let ele = new CustomElement();
        document.body.appendChild(ele);
      }
    );
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
</body>
</html>
```

And this works just fine. I get the two alerts just like I expect them.

Comment: It all seem logical.. but.. it does not work even without defer.. I really don't know what could be wrong there.. the class definition works well because in HTML the elememt gets loaded, but only when defer is present.. but in code defer or not males no difference

Comment: When I put the whole class definition before the init method then it works as well.. but not when imported from a file..

Comment: Did you try my alternate version of your `init` function? That code waits until you call `customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement );` and that can not be called until after your code is loaded and your class defined.

Comment: I did but it was still undefined.. don't know what is the problem there..

Comment: You don't even have to wait for `customElements.whenDefined` since `init` is being executed only **after** `DOMContentLoaded`, when `document.readyState === 'complete'` (in contrast to it being `interactive` when `DOMContentLoaded` is going on. By that time any script with `defer` **must** have executed, because defer not only waits for `DOMContentLoaded`, but also delays the end of it until the script has been executed.

Comment: I just did a quick test and @connexo is correct. The script file gets loaded first, then the `DOMContentLoaded` event is triggered, then the `onLoad` calls the `init` function. So the call to `customElements.whenDefined` is not really needed in this example.

Comment: Ok.. I tried it and it works without whenDefined.. interesting

Comment: Then I pasted my whole custom elements file and it did not work.. then I looked at what why.. and my custom_elements.js had a "switch" that checked whether the browser supports custom elements and loaded them only when yes.. but this apparently defined them for some local scope or something so when I moved my elements outside the if(){ }else{ } structure it did work..
Thank you very much guys for your help..

Answer (score 0):

**defer** - The script will get executed when the page has finished parsing.

Meaning - your `CustomElement` will be executed after the call for it has been made.

How to avoid - 
  Remove the defer and use the script tag at just before the end of your body tag.

Comment: So when I put my script import before the end of body without defer that could work ?..  that makes some sense.. that is an option I did not try.. I will do that..

Comment: Not working either.. the only time it worked was when I copied the class definition above the init function..